# Struggling with simple Bootstrap dropdown not extending in Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get this navbar dropdown button to work. Other than displaying a down arrow the only click action I can achieve is to follow the `href`. Which creates a useless trigger example.com/# and not the drop down link list that I am trying to create.

I have the required JS scripts loaded into my HTML header.

Here is the full navbar code:

```
<div class="masthead">
<h3 class="text-muted">example.com</h3>
<br />
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-justified col-xs-2 col-sm-1">
  <li><a href="../index">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="../../_site/Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../_site/Business">Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../_site/Automobile">Automobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../_site/Family">Family</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../_site/Community">Community</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../_site/National Parks">National Parks</a></li>
    </ul></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="Blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
```

Seems simple right? But why is it not working? Kudos.

Comment: Make sure you have Bootstrap's js, and a compatible version of jQuery. If you're doing a `dropdown` then the `data-target` attribute isn't needed. You can check out Bootstrap's example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).

Comment: Removing the `data-target` has no effect on the functioning of the navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be something with the way you include scripts. Please check chrome console output and paste it here.

I just pasted your code in my bootstrap project and it works out of the box (i removed href="#" from

```
<a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. maybe you aren't including bootstrap.js files?? Maybe you aren't including jquery?

Comment: Moved the bootstrap.js below where I import JQuery in my header doc. <'duh>

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it helped :)